# GCP Cloud SQL - 250 of 2000

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

In GCP Cloud SQL for mySQL,

Say for Network throughput (MB/s) it specified
250 of 2000
Is 250 the average value and 2000 the maximum value attainable?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the question mark (to the left of your red square] it will lead you to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/network-bandwidth). You will see that limiting factor is 16 Gbps.

Now using [converter](https://www.gbmb.org/gbps-to-mbs), 16 Gbps is 2000MB/s.

If you change your machine type to high mem, 8 vCPU or 16, you will see the cap at 2000. So i suspect 250MB/s is the allocated value for the machine type you chose, the 1cpu.

Comment: Close - 250 MB/s is the allocated value (as in quota or limit) based upon the configuration.

Comment: @John Hanley, ty ill change theoretical to allocated value.

Comment: Quibble - 'b' for bits, 'B' for bytes.  So 16 Gbps is 2000 MBps.   2000 Mbps (bits) happens to be the egress cap for a 1 vCPU VM in GCP.

Comment: Edited to from 2000 Mb/s to 2000MB/s ty @rick jones